# When is the set $A=\{a+s|a\in I , s\in S \}$ a prime ideal of R?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be commutative ring with identity, $I$ an ideal of $R$, and $S$ a subset of $R$.

> Under what conditions is the set $A=\{a+s\mid a\in I , s\in S \}$:
>   1- an *ideal* of $R$?
>   2-  a *prime ideal* of $R$?

Of course one trivial candidate is the case where  either $I$ or $S$ is a prime ideal containing the other.
  Thank you for any help.